# Generalization of identity for terminating hypergeometric function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

Let ${}_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ be the ordinary hypergeometric function for $z \in \mathbb{C}$
\begin{equation}
{}_2F_1(a,b;c;z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k!} \frac{(a)_{k} (b)_k}{(c)_k}\,,
\end{equation}
where the coefficients $(a)_k, (b)_k,(b)_k$ are the usual Pochhammer symbols or rising factorials. For the special terminating case of $a = -n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, this series reduces to a polynomial. Let now $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $c,1+b-c-n \neq 0,-1,\dots,-n+1$, then [this review](https://wiredspace.wits.ac.za/handle/10539/13019) gives the identity
\begin{equation}
{}_2F_1(-n,b;c;1-z) = \frac{(c-b)_{n}}{(c)_n} {}_2F_1(-n,b;1+b-c-n;z)\,.
\end{equation}
They mention that this can be proven by induction. My question now is if there is a generalization of this identity to more general terminating hypergeometric functions like the generalized hypergeometric function ${}_pF_q$ as it is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) (or of course other functions)? Or maybe anyone sees how the above can be proven without induction, such that I can maybe try to generalize it with the help of it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would attempt to prove it using the WZ-method, i.e. find a linear ODE that annihilates both sides, then match initial conditions. Then you look at the induced recurrence for the coefficients (it will be first order, as it is for all hypergeometrics), and see if you can generalize it there.

Comment: This is a good tip, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the reason you want a non-inductive proof is that induction requires you to know your goal before you start, but there's actually a simple way to find out what the result *could be*. Assume that the general identity is of the form

$$F(-n,\vec{b};\vec{c};1-z) = \alpha_n(\vec{b},\vec{c}) F(-n,\vec{u};\vec{v};z)$$ where $\alpha_n$ is independent of $z$. Then we have an identity of polynomials, which is just an identity of coefficients. Expanding

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-n)_k \prod_{b_i \in \vec{b}}(b_i)_k}{\prod_{c_i \in \vec{c}}(c_i)_k} \frac{(1-z)^k}{k!} = \alpha_n(\vec{b},\vec{c}) \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{(-n)_j \prod_{u_i \in \vec{u}}(u_i)_j}{\prod_{v_i \in \vec{v}}(v_i)_j} \frac{z^j}{j!}$$

we get that for $0 \le j \le n$,

$$(-1)^j \sum_{k=j}^n \frac{(-n+j)_{k-j} \prod_{b_i \in \vec{b}}(b_i)_k}{(k-j)! \prod_{c_i \in \vec{c}}(c_i)_k} = \alpha_n(\vec{b},\vec{c}) \frac{\prod_{u_i \in \vec{u}}(u_i)_j}{\prod_{v_i \in \vec{v}}(v_i)_j}$$

From the case $j=n$ we derive

$$\alpha_n(\vec{b},\vec{c}) = (-1)^n \frac{\prod_{b_i \in \vec{b}}(b_i)_n}{\prod_{c_i \in \vec{c}}(c_i)_n} \frac{\prod_{v_i \in \vec{v}}(v_i)_n}{\prod_{u_i \in \vec{u}}(u_i)_n}$$

From the case $j=n-1$ we derive

$$(-1)^{n-1} \frac{\prod_{b_i \in \vec{b}}(b_i)_{n-1}}{\prod_{c_i \in \vec{c}}(c_i)_{n-1}} \left(1 - \frac{\prod_{b_i \in \vec{b}} (b_i+n-1)}{\prod_{c_i \in \vec{c}} (c_i+n-1)} \right) = \alpha_n(\vec{b},\vec{c}) \frac{\prod_{u_i \in \vec{u}}(u_i)_{n-1}}{\prod_{v_i \in \vec{v}}(v_i)_{n-1}}$$

Putting them together,

$$\frac{\prod_{v_i \in \vec{v}} (v_i+n-1)}{\prod_{u_i \in \vec{u}} (u_i+n-1)} 
 = 1 - \frac{\prod_{c_i \in \vec{c}} (c_i+n-1)}{\prod_{b_i \in \vec{b}} (b_i+n-1)}$$

In the case that $\vec{b} = b$ and $\vec{c} = c$, the RHS is simply $1 - \frac{c+n-1}{b+n-1} = \frac{b-c}{b+n-1}$ and identifying $v+n-1 = b-c$, $u+n-1=b+n-1$ gives the parameters of the quoted theorem. If we have e.g. $\vec{b} = (b_1,b_2)$, $\vec{c} = (c_1,c_2)$ then the RHS is $$\frac{(b_1+n-1)(b_2+n-1)-(c_1+n-1)(c_2+n-1)}{(b_1+n-1)(b_2+n-1)} = \frac{(b_1 + b_2 - c_1 - c_2)n + (b_1-1)(b_2-1) - (c_1-1)(c_2-1)}{(b_1+n-1)(b_2+n-1)}$$

which is suggestive that the most general identity possible requires $b_1 + b_2 - c_1 - c_2 = 1$. I haven't considered also the case $j=n-2$, but it would add a further constraint which would probably tell you exactly what is worth trying to prove. In any case, it seems that $\vec{u} = \vec{b}$.

Comment: Back-substituting $\alpha$ into the general term and substituting $r=n-j$ gives $$\frac{\prod_{v_i \in \vec{v}} (v_i+n-r)_r}{\prod_{u_i \in \vec{u}} (u_i+n-r)_r} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^r (-1)^k \binom{r}{k}\prod_{b_i \in \vec{b}} (b_i+n-r)_{r-k} \prod_{c_i \in \vec{c}} (c_i+n-k)_k}{\prod_{b_i \in \vec{b}} (b_i+n-r)_r}$$ which is a form suitable for experimenting with a CAS. So far my experiments with Sage haven't found anything sensible for ${}_3F_2$.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will look into it more closely. I have so far only experimented around with possible generalizations in ${}_3F_2$ but have not found anything useful.